# App Engine Datastore - devserver limits

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to test the efficiency of the Google App Engine Datastore database. I want to know how fast it will query over a large dataset. And by large, I mean like 5-10mil entities of the same kind.

The devserver only lets me input 1000 entities of the same kind. Is there a way to up this limit? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you're talking about the admin interface on http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/? If you want to insert many entries, you should be using code, or the [bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html). There's no limit on the number of entries you can insert using those methods.

This won't be particularly illustrative, though: The performance of the dev_appserver datastore is not representative of the performance of the production datastore. dev_appserver currently stores data in memory, so once you exceed what can be held in your physical RAM, it will slow down dramatically. Obviously, nothing similar applies to the production datastore!

Comment: Thanks Nick! This is all very new to me and I'm doing my best to absorb it all. I'm inserting entities using code, but I can only see 1,000 entities in the admin interface. I understand what you mean. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: You only see 1000 entities in the local admin console due to the '1000 entity limit' - now abolished, but still extant in the dev_appserver. If you do a more specific query, you'll see that all the results are there.