# How can I save more than 1000 records in an Entity in the GoogleAppEngine Datastore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a site in Python through GoogleappEngine.

I need to store a large amount of data (financial data) that will be later shown on request by users.

The problem is that when I try to save them, it only saves 1000 records in one of the entities.

I just iterate data from a file and save it in this way:

```
# Save in database
b = FinancialData (ticker = ticker, period_type = period_type, year = year, coaCode =      coaCode, value = value)
b.put()
```

Not sure if I am doing something wrong, I have not much experience in this database or if I should configure it.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you checked your quotas? There is the possibility to exceed your available quotas. Do you get any error on the logs?  Provide more information please so as to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are experiencing this problem on your local development server and not when deployed on actual server, your questions has been answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9543034/96313